# How to map the file path in the provider xml file that matches files downloaded to the ‘DirectoryDownloads’ location

Tags: android, xamarin, download, apk

A request has been composed to the DownloadManager that specifies the download directory.

```
request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(_context, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, downloadName);
```

This on the system being tested results in a file at the following file path
file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myco.myapp/files/Download/com.myco.myapp.version.apk

Question is what needs to go in the file_paths.xml file?

The file_paths.xal file is referenced by

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.myco.myapp.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

In the manifest

And is used by GetUriForFile like this:

```
var uri = global::Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this._context.ApplicationContext, providerName, apkPath);
```

where providerName is ="com.myco.myapp.fileprovider"
and apkPath is the download path above.

I have not found an entry for the file_paths.xml file that does not result in
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Failed to find configured root that contains file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myco.myapp/files/Download/com.myco.myapp.version.apk

Except for:

```
<root-path name="root" path="." />
```

Which results in an output content uri of
content://com.myco.myapp.fileprovider/root/file%3A/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myco.myapp/files/Download/com.myco.myapp.version.apk

Which not surprisingly fails to install.

I am anticipating that a line along the lines of

```
<SOMETHING-path name="downloads" path="Download/" />
```

Will result in content://downloads/com.myco.myapp.version.apk

But all the SOMETHING-path variants I have tried have failed.

I have also tried path="Download" path="Download/"and path="/Download"
On all the varients.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test  with it?

Comment: The required code is too large to post here, I have therefore uploaded a complete sample here https://github.com/BrianDT/DownloadAndInstallAndroidApkIssueSample

Comment: Note that to see the error in the sample above it needs to be executed on a device running Android 7 or above.